# How to compile SNAP c++ source code without getting architecture error?

Tags: c++, architecture, clang

I want to compile SNAP (*Stanford Network Analysis Project*) c++ source code using terminal on mac by running the `make all` command and I'm getting the following error:

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Initially I was getting this error:

`clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`

but I found that I should replace the `g++` in the `Makefile.config` with `gcc-10` which I installed using the homebrew and now I'm getting the architecture error!

I'm on mac os Big Sur 11.0.1 and everything is up to date! Does anyone have any clue?

[clang error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1AuO.png)

[architecture error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONNrz.png)

[Makefile.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJGpX.png)

Comment: please don't post links to errors. Don't post images of code/errors/text, instead copy paste them.

Comment: from the [official resource](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-2011/tutorial/tutorial.html):  "you will find that under Linux, you should uncomment the two lines:
`#CXXFLAGS += -std=c++98 -Wall` 
`#LDFLAGS += -lrt`" have you followed these steps?

Comment: @bolov I think only the Darwin part of the config is used when compiling on mac. Anyway I tried what you said right now, and still I'm getting the same error! (LDFLAGS += -lrt is uncommented by default)